# DOTA is hanging after launch

Tags: windows-xp, memory, cpu

- 1 GB RAM
- Pentium 4 processor
- No graphics card, 128 MB default for the GUI.
- Windows XP SP2.

When I play DOTA, the game runs up to 1 minute only. After that, the entire OS crashes. My drivers are up to date. My friends are able to play, even with 512 MB RAM.

What could be the problem? Is there any constraint on physical RAM for a 32bit OS when gaming with that processor?

Comment: Please please PLEASE use spellcheck. Also more information on your system would be nice.

Comment: Hi, I closed your question because it lacks useful information. What OS, when does it crash (startup or mid-game), are your drivers up to date, what GPU do you have etc. So if you update your question with this information, it might get reopened, but as it is right now, it stays closed

Comment: Dude. I added other info also. Plz help this innocent gamer :(

Comment: @Inz4n3_DeviLop3R When writing questions please add detail and any information that may help us like system specs (in your case).

Comment: thankz dude. Any more details needed.PLz leme know. Can u suggest any software that can help to support game:/

Comment: Has the game ever ran fine in the past? Or has it always had this problem? Also, edit your post with this information.

Comment: It is d first time i am trying DOTA in PC. I am able to run other games like CS1.6 with this configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lack of a discrete graphics card may be your issue. DOTA 2 is based off the Source engine which requires a discrete graphics card, *or* a fairly powerful integrated card to run.

CS is a lot older and based off Half-Life (which is *really* old) and probably has significantly lower requirements.

DOTA 1 is a Warcraft 3 mod, and has relatively low system requirements. That said, I had a proper graphics card running it back in the day. Integrated graphics just aren't supported as well.

[System requirements for Dota 2](http://www.dota-utilities.com/2011/09/dota-2-system-requirements.html):

```
Operating System: Windows XP, Vista or Windows 7
Processor: Intel Pentium 4 @ 3.0 GHz or AMD Athlon equivalent
RAM: 1 GB
Hard Disk: 4 GB of free space
Video Card: nVidia GeForce 7600 GS or ATI Radeon X1600 series
Sound Card: DirectX 9 Compatible
DirectX: Version 9.0c
Broadband Internet Connection
```

[Requirements for HL1](http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=14496&tab=sysreqs) (the 3D engine CS uses)

```
Minimum CPU Type: Pentium
Minimum CPU Speed: 133 MHz
Minimum RAM Required: 24 MB
Minimum Hard Disk Space: 400 MB
Graphics Type: SVGA
Graphics Resolution: Multiple Resolutions
Color Depth: High Color
```

Requirements for Warcraft III (which dota is a mod of)

```
400 MHz Pentium II or equivalent
128 MB of RAM
8 MB 3D video card (TNT, i810, Voodoo 3, Rage 128 equivalent or better) with DirectX® 8.1 support
700 MB HD space
4X CD-ROM drive
```

As you can see, they are *vastly* different.

My recommendation is really to get a graphics card.

Comment: +1 I'm almost sure its the lack of a graphics card.

Comment: If i increase inbuilt graphics from 128 to 256 or more. Will it damage any hardware components..

Comment: No. it also won't do you any good

Comment: I think he is asking for DOTA not DOTA 2.

Comment: added WC3/DOTA specs as well. That *should* run in theory tho. I assumed it was DOTA 2, since DOTA is a WC3 mod, and i would suppose be run through it as well.

Comment: The application is now showing a FATAL ERROR window. "THE MEMORY COULD NOT BE READ"